# Find files with the exception list of file name in separate file

Tags: grep, find

I have 10 files in a directory..

```
test1.txt
test2.txt
test3.txt
.
.
test10.txt
```

Also a exclude file names exclude.txt which have the below file names

```
test1.txt
test2.txt
test3.txt
text4.txt
```

I need to have a find command which exclude the file name from the exclude file and provide the results.

```
test5.txt
test6.txt
test7.txt
text8.txt
test9.txt
text10.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for file in *.txt;do grep ${file} exclude.txt >/dev/null;r=${?}; if [ $r -ne 0 ]; then echo ${file};fi;done| grep -v exclude.txt
```

if your exclude.txt is not in the same directory, you can omit the last `grep`command after the pipe `|`

Answer (score 0):

This isn't pretty but gets the job done :)

```
find . -regextype posix-extended  \! -regex "\./($(cat exclude.txt | tr '\n' '|')).*$"
```

Note: this will only work if there's no NEWLINE on the last line of the exclude.txt ...

Answer (score 0):

You can run your `find` command and then do an inverse `grep` for the files listed in your text file:

```
find | grep -v -f exclude.list
```

However this would also exclude a dir with said name, e.g. `dir/test1.txt/actual_file`, i.e. is not limited to the file being the last part of your `find` results.

To take care of this problem, add `$` to the end of your exclude list entries, to make sure they are matching only at the end of a line:

```
test1.txt$
```

and so on.

On the fly this would look like

```
find | grep -v -f <( sed 's/$/$/' exclude.list )
```

Maybe also add the `-type f` option to make sure your results include files only.